# How to edit MDN sidebar contents?

Tags: javascript

I think the JavaScript contents of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is one of the best out there. It's very easy for us to contribute by just click the Edit icon of the page(for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), type your code/text and save changes.

But is there anyone know how to edit the sidebar contents - {{jsSidebar}}?

Thanks.